# Rails for Zombies Level 5 Challenge 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-for-zombies

The problem statement is 
Create a named route. It should generate a path like '/zombies/:name' where :name is a parameter, and points to the index action in ZombiesController. Name the route 'graveyard'

the resources are 
Resources

```
zombies
id  name    graveyard
1   Ash     Glen Haven Memorial Cemetary
2   Bob     Chapel Hill Cemetary
3   Jim     My Fathers Basement
```

my solution is

```
TwitterForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
  match ':name' => 'Zombies#index', :as => 'graveyard'
end
```

i also tried

```
TwitterForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
      match ':name' => 'Zombie#index', :as => 'graveyard'
    end
```

the error that i get in both cases is

```
Sorry, Try Again
Did not route to ZombiesController index action with :name parameter
```

What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
match '/zombies/:name',:to=> 'zombies#index', :as => 'graveyard'

RailsForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :zombie
    match '/zombies/:name',:to=> 'Zombies#index', :as => 'graveyard'
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
match '/zombies/:name' => 'zombies#index', :as => 'graveyard'
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails for Zombies has been updated for Rails 4. The *match* method has been deprecated. Rails now requires specifying which HTTP verb (such as *get*) to respond to. For the updated Level 5 Challenge 5 of Rails for Zombies, this is one possible solution:

```
TwitterForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/zombies/:name', to: 'zombies#index', :as => 'graveyard'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this work for me

```
RailsForZombies::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'zombies/:name' => 'Zombies#index' , :as => "graveyard"
  #match ':name' => 'Zombie#index', :as => 'graveyard'
  #match 'zombies/:name',:to=> 'zombies#index', :as => 'graveyard'
end
```